# ArcGIS Pro - Cannot zoom in beyond 1:1 in Layout (can't get to 1:0.5) but can in Map View

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, scale

CS: California State Plane Zone II

I have a point feature class with 3 points in it. These points are separated by about an inch (x y and z). In map view, I can zoom in beyond 1:1 (1:0.2 for example, see attached). In Layout view, I cannot go beyond 1:1, whether using the mouse or typing in a number.

I would like to show the distance between these points (x, and y) and so a finer map scale is what I need in Layout view.

My paper size is Arch D - 36x24.

[image: Layout View]ArcGIS Pro 2.5.2
[image: Map View]

Comment: Just encountered this myself, did you resolve it?

Comment: I did not, and I worked at it for a long time.